# Error when trying to import stock exchange data (yahoo)

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests, yahoo-finance, pandas-datareader

I have a problem when I try to import the historical data of each company in python. Here is my code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
import pandas_datareader as web

import pandas_datareader as web
ticker = pd.read_csv("nasdaq_screener_1611015840705.csv")['Symbol']
df = pd.DataFrame

for symbol in ticker:
  df[symbol] = web.DataReader(symbol, data_source = 'yahoo', start = '2013-01-01', end = '2020-12-29')['Adj Close']
```

However, on the last line of code, I got an error :

[image: picture of the error]

My goal is to make something which looks like this :

[image: picture here]

Comment: You can just do `df = web.DataReader(ticker.unique(), data_source='yahoo', start='2013-01-01', end='2020-12-29')['Adj Close']`.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinneyThanks, should I keep the `for symbol in ticker: `?

Comment: No, you don’t need the loop.

Comment: Thanks it helped me lot!